# How can I flip a column of data vertically in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

How can I flip a column of data vertically in Google Spreadsheet?

E.g. if the column is:

```
Bob
Alice
Calamari
```

I want:

```
Calamari
Alice
Bob
```

Comment: Are You looking dora a built-in featuare (like a menu or keyboard shortcut) a fórmula, macro or a script? Also please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask]

Comment: Have you tried any of the solutions offered? Did any work for you? If not we should try finding out why. If yes, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and maybe [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following formula:

```
=SORT(B2:B11,ROW(B2:B11)*N(B2:B11<>""),0)
```

**Functions used**:
[SORT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150?hl=en-GB) *(Sorts the rows of a given array or range by the values in one or more columns.)*
[ROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316?hl=en-GB) *(Returns the row number of a specified cell.)*
[N](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093357?hl=en-GB) *(Returns the argument provided as a number.)*

Comment: Excellent slightly more complicated solution that supports filtering out unwanted values (in this case blanks) , thanks for the function breakdown

Answer (score 3):

```
=SORT(A1:A3,ROW(A1:A3),FALSE)
```

You can just use sort row, make it false to descending.

Comment: Your solution does not take into account empty cells. If you try sorting the whole column `A1:A` you will end up with cell `A1` being on the last row of your sheet *(row 1000 or worst)*

Comment: Excellent straightforward solution if you know the exact range and don't need filtering 